# React Redux connect is throwing a call signature error with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am writing this component, however, I am receiving the following error while trying to use the higher order function connect from `react-redux`. I believe I have defined the types correctly. What I am doing wrong?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import connect from 'react-redux'
import {ExperimentsState, Root} from "../../types/somepath.redux";
import {Dispatch} from "redux";
import experimentActions from "../../redux/actions/experimentActions";


type StateToProps = {
    experiments: ExperimentsState;
};

type DispatchToProps = {
    fetchExperiments(): () => void;
}

type SignalsHomePageContainerProps = StateToProps & DispatchToProps

class SignalsHomePageContainer extends Component<SignalsHomePageContainerProps, ExperimentsState> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hi, I am container
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: Root) => ({
    experiments: state.experiments.data
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    fetchExperiments: () => dispatch(experimentActions.fetchExperiments())
})

export default connect<StateToProps, DispatchToProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignalsHomePageContainer);
```

The error I am receiving pertaining to the `connect` function is as follows:

> TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("somepath/node_modules/@types/react-redux/index")' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: You've a typo, `connect` is a named export, not a default export, e.g. `import { connect } from 'react-redux'`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: Please also be aware that you are writing an extremely old style of React and Redux. If this is not on a legacy project, you are probably following extremely outdated documentation. 
In modern React, you should not be using class components any more, and the `connect` HOC at this point is also only a tool for backwards compat with class components. If you are interested in learning about modern Redux, which is about 1/4 of the code, please read [this documentation page](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today).

Comment: Yes, I am making changes on legacy project, thank you for the additional link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the brackets around `connect` in your imports, so connect is instead the entire module, instead of a function.

```js
// Should be:
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// Instead of:
import connect from 'react-redux'
```

Comment: @phry Issues that are caused by typos aren't much help to anyone other than the OP, right now, they don't make for good longterm content on SO's QnA platform. That's why there's even a specific close reason for them.

Comment: @DrewReese but doing a default import instead of a named import is not a typo, it's using the wrong feature, not knowing the difference. Of course the answer can educate more than it does, but this is not a "typo fix" solution.

Comment: @phry The question wasn't about how to import or what the difference is between default and named exports/imports, which is surely a duplicate. I view it as forgetting to include the curly boys, which is a typographical error.

Comment: From chat experience I can say that many beginners are just not aware that the curly braces have a meaning at all, or which meaning. It can be a great teaching moment.